# Retrofit Passes empty body to POST request

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit, retrofit2

I am trying to make a POST request to my WebAPI using retrofit 2 to pass data in Body of request but it passes EMPTY Body for API. Then API returns a BAD REQUEST 400 CODE.

Here is my service interface.

```
public interface MyClient {

    @POST("feedbacks")
    Call<Feedback> sendFeedback(@Body Feedback feedback);
}
```

Here is my feedback Class.

```
public class Feedback {
    @SerializedName("Feedback_ID")
    @Expose
    private Integer Feedback_ID;
    @SerializedName("Feed")
    @Expose
    private String Feed;

    public Feedback(String feed) {
        Feed = feed;
    }

    public Integer getFeedback_ID() {
        return Feedback_ID;
    }
}
```

Here I make request on a Button click event.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view == sendButton) {
            if (!feedbackEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                Feedback feedback = new Feedback(
                        feedbackEditText.getText().toString()
                );
                sendFeedback(feedback);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(ActivityFeedBack.this, getResources().getString(R.string.activity_feedback_feedbackFieldIsEmpty), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

And finally Here is my request method

```
private void sendFeedback(Feedback feedback) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_ENDPOINT)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

        Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

        MyClient myClient = retrofit.create(MyClient.class);
        Call<Feedback> call = myClient.sendFeedback(feedback);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Feedback>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Feedback> call, Response<Feedback> response) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "DONE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, response.message(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Feedback> call, Throwable t) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Toast.makeText(activity, call.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

All Helps will be appreciated.thanks.

Comment: did you try to add a log interceptor to check data sended? Just to be sure

Comment: change @POST("feedbacks") to @POST("/feedbacks")

Comment: @appersiano No didnt. let me check what is the result.thanks.

Comment: @jmarkstar I have that / in my API_ENDPOINT link. The problem is not with that

Comment: @appersiano Thanks alot bro . with logging I got lots of information. Actually application sends the body. But the problem was with my server And just did some configuration in my IIS server so the problem solve. Here I am providing a link which also help me in solving the problem. http://blog.binarybits.net/applications/iis-express-http-error-400-the-request-hostname-is-invalid/

Comment: you are welcome @Mohammad Naim Dahee

Comment: same problem here. :(
https://stackoverflow.com/q/65734273/1906738

Answer (score 0):

I think That is happening because the @Expose annotation is being used, try removing them from your request body class or add this on your gson:

```
private Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
    .build();
```

I hope It could help you.

Comment: Thanks for your consideration bro. but the problem was not with @Expose

Comment: Maybe you should specify the content-type, try this: @POST("/feedbacks")
    Call<Feedback> sendFeedback(@Header("Content-Type") String contentType, @Body Feedback feedback); and set "application/json" as its value.

Comment: If that is not the problem, I recommend you to test the service using a tool such as PostMan, you should check if the services is working fine before to think the problem is on your side.

Comment: Yes bro the problem is not with the code . Code is just working fine. after some logging I found out that the server does not allow the request which is coming from genymotion emulator. I brought some changes on my IIS server configuration and it solved the problem. This link helped me in solving the problem. http://blog.binarybits.net/applications/iis-express-http-error-400-the-request-hostname-is-invalid/